# Getting asynchronous view data on button click using spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am making a web application using spring mvc but I am stuck here. I have a page login.jsp inside WEB-INF folder and I have three types of query string associated with this view.

> "login.fin?cmdAction=selectLogin" -> this will display two
>   buttons->Admin Login and Trainee Login.

On click of admin Login button the page should go to `"login.fin?cmdAction=adminLogin"` which will display page for login of admin.

and on click of Trainee login button it should go to `"login.fin?cmdAction=traineeLogin"` which will display Trainee Login Page.

This is my loginController:

```
package com.finlogic.loginapps.login.apps;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

public class LoginController extends MultiActionController {

public ModelAndView selectLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
        modelAndView.addObject("title", "Select Login");
        return modelAndView;
    }
public ModelAndView adminLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
        modelAndView.addObject("title", "Admin");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    public ModelAndView traineeLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
        modelAndView.addObject("title", "Trainee");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

This is my login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>${title} Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/login.js">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
    <div class="wrap-login100">
        <c:if test="${title eq 'Select Login'}">

                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27" >
                        Select:
                </span>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn" id="adminloginselect" onclick="adminLoader()">
                            Admin Login
                    </button>
                </div><br/>
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn" id="traineeloginselect" onclick="traineeLoader()">
                        Trainee Login
                    </button>
                </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${title eq 'Admin'}">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                    Admin Log in:
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="adminusername" placeholder="Admin Username">
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="adminpass" placeholder="Admin Password">
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                    <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                    <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                    <a class="txt1" href="#">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
            </c:if>
        <c:if test="${title eq 'Trainee'}">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                    Log in
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="traineeusername" placeholder="Trainee Username">
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="traineepass" placeholder="Trainee Password">
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                    <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                    <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                    <a class="txt1" href="#">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form></c:if>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript for above page is
login.js

```
 function adminLoader()
    {
        getSynchronousData('login.fin?cmdAction=adminLogin','','container');
    }
    function traineeLoader()
    {
        getSynchronousData('login.fin?cmdAction=traineeLogin','','container');
    }
    function getSynchronousData(datSource,params,destination)
    {
        var XMLHttpRequestObject=false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
            XMLHttpRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequestObject();
                }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            {
            XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            var obj=document.getElementById(destination);
            obj.innerHTML=varLoading;
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST",datSource,false);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(params);
            if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==4)
            {
                    if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==200)
                    {              
                      obj.innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    obj.innerHTML=varProblem;
                    }
                }

            }
    }
```

When I click on admin login, nothing happens onclick. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Fix datsourc to datSource
Change your js code to the code below:

```
function adminLoader()
{
   function adminLoader('login.fin','adminLogin','container')
}
function traineeLoader()
{
    getSynchronousData('login.fin','traineeLogin','container');
}
function getSynchronousData(datSource,val,destination)
{
    var obj=document.getElementById(destination);
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequestObject();
            }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            obj.innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
          }
        else
          {
                obj.innerHTML=varProblem;
          }
    }
    var params = "cmdAction=" + val;
    xmlhttp.open("POST",datSource,true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
    obj.innerHTML=varLoading; //<----why?
}
```

Comment: which browser do you use, if chrome type ctrl+shit+I and take a look whether there are any indicating errors

Comment: 5login.fin?cmdAction=selectLogin:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequestObject is not defined
    at getSynchronousData (login.fin?cmdAction=selectLogin:34)
    at adminLoader (login.fin?cmdAction=selectLogin:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.fin?cmdAction=selectLogin:73)                                                                                     I got this.

Comment: I edited the code, try that on, sory for inattention

Comment: Thank You. I edited the javascript still the same error comes.